# Cant run custom script in rails 4 in heroku but localhost yes

Tags: javascript, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, production-environment

I've finally resorted to putting my question here.

I did the tutorial in http://ruby.railstutorial.org and completed it all the way to before adding the microposts (i wanted to create a basic user managment first). Everything works fine on localhost.

I did the following mod so as to have a fading out alert that works in localhost but not in heroku.

#### assets/javascript/custom.js.coffee ###

```
$ ->
  flashCallback = ->
    $(".alert-info").fadeOut()
  $(".alert-info").bind 'click', (ev) =>
    $(".alert-info").fadeOut()
  setTimeout flashCallback, 10000

  #source http://traz.github.io/tips/2013/tips-modal-effect/
```

#### config/environment/production.rb ### (cleaned comments for readability)

```
SampleApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

#### Gemfile

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.1.1'
  gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
  group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'sprockets_better_errors'
  end
  gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.5.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.1.0'
  gem 'turbolinks' , '2.2.1'
  gem 'jbuilder', '1.5.3'

  group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
  end

  group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
  end
  gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5'
  gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
  gem 'faker','1.3.0'
  gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5'
  gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap','1.0.0'
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried disable enforcing SSL - e.g. `config.force_ssl = false`?

Comment: are you precompiling your assets before you push to heroku?

Comment: my push to heroku is the following command  

git add . && git commit -m "Add custom flash with fadeout" && git push && git push heroku master &&  heroku run rake assets:precompile 

i also tried with config.force_ssl = false

Comment: also there are no errors when running heroku logs

Answer (score 0):

after all the stuff i did it works.
this includes:

reformating the js.coffee code
doing a local precompile
including the local precompile in the push to heroku.

these things by themselves did not work.

the only thing is that locally now im getting a js error in the custom.js.coffee

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
$ ->
```

in the arrow. when checkin source there is no arrow. wierd but as long as it works...